# How to get particular venue list like party/cafe/nightlife using Facebook graph API for particular city

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I want to get venue list (pub/cafe/nightlife) for particular city where party's   happens using Facebook grap.
I am using following graph API request but it is returning all hotels and venue list:

```
$link1= "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=restaurant,pune&type=place&fields=name,category,location,category_list&access_token=$resfb->fb_access_token";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only search for events by name, but not by location. And you can only search places by location - not by city, but only by geolocation. See the docs for the specifications: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

Comment: response of this request containing venue category as hotels/restaurant/pub/bar/local business for city 'pune' as i mentioned in request but it is retuning all types of venue and i need few like nightclub/bar/pub etc.